# How do you stretch a JPanel within a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

Here is an image of what I'm working with:
[image]

And Here is what I would like to acheive:
[image]

As you can see, I have an JPanel Outer with a GridLayout of (3, 1)...i.e. 3 row and 1 column

I added 3 JPanels within the Outer JPanel, but the problem I have is stretching just the Inner2 JPanel. I need more space to add more info in Inner2 and want less space for Inner3 because it only has a CHECKOUT JButton.

How would I go about achieving this?

I have tried to set different layouts within Inner2 but it seems like the dimension of all the Inner JPanels are FIXED.

Comment: Desktop applications are slowly becoming obsolete. Especially for tasks like this. I'd suggest thinking about writing a web application, but that's just me. Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a GridLayout because the components will always be the same size.

Maybe you can use a `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayout`. Or maybe even a `BorderLayout` would be better to use since it allows the CENTER panel to grow as much as it needs.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for an example of using the above layouts.

Comment: +1 for the `BorderLayout`. Three panels underneath each other, and only the middle one must stretch ... sounds like the definition of a `BorderLayout`

Comment: So you're saying I should use a borderlayout, the NORTH for Inner1,CENTER for Inner2 and SOUTH for Inner3?